# OS X: What might cause ssh-agent to stop providing passphrase for encrypted SSH private key?

Tags: macos, security, ssh, openssl, private-key

As far as I can tell, the only thing I did was modify my `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file, because I set up a new Parallels VM with a Bridged Network Adapter and the client Linux gained a local LAN IP which matched a previous entry in the known hosts file (thus preventing me from connecting to it).

(I'm not sure if this is the cause, but) I edited my known hosts file, and sometime after, when pushing to git, SSH started asking me to provide the password for the private key, which it had never done up to that point (since setting up the machine in February).

I now realize I should have at least run `ssh` with a verbose flag to see what was happening, and i have since learned about `ssh-add` and `ssh-agent` and all that, and I'm guessing `ssh-add -l` might have told me it stopped "tracking" it or something so i could "re-add" it with `ssh-add`.

My question is, could manually editing the known hosts file possibly have triggered `ssh-agent` to stop saving the private key passphrase as a security measure? If not, is there anything that would trigger this, that I may have inadvertently done between the times that I did any pushing with git?

What I did was:

- verify my `~/.ssh/id_rsa` was encrypted. Got slightly confused about why I never got prompted for said passphrase (hardly remember setting it up with one, but I probably did)
- decrypted it with `openssl rsa -in ~/.ssh/id_rsa -out ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
- got my pushing done
- found out about `ssh-agent`, thought, hmm, explains why I never got prompted for passphrase, I should set it up like it was since my file is now plaintext
- encrypted it with `ssh-keygen -p -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

And I was slightly surprised to find that it is no longer asking me for the private key encryption passphrase anymore after I re-encrypted the private key using that last command. `ssh-add -l` now reports one entry (mentioning that very file, `~/.ssh/id_rsa`). I only wish I ran `ssh-add -l` prior to decrypting the private key.

Is everything still kosher?  Did I get hacked?

Comment: I have continued to mess around with VMs and so IPs are continuing to be reused (DHCP at work) and I have since edited out another entry from `known-hosts`, but I have not been prompted for my key passphrase again yet.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same thing happen and was likewise concerned about being hacked.  I still don't know exactly what happened, which is disconcerting.

Anyway, here's what I do whenever I'm suddenly asked for my passphrase:

```
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
$ ssh-add
```

It will ask me one more time for my passphrase then that's it.